# Webflow execution id missing when using g:link

Tags: grails, grails-webflow

We have recently upgraded a project from grails version 2.3.11 to 2.5.5. In the process the webflow plugin was updated from 2.0.8.1 to 2.1.0.

To controll webflow I use the g:link tag, like this:

```
<g:link event="foo">Foo action</g:link>
```

Before the update, the link url was correctly build, and looked like this:
`/fooaction/superflow?execution=e1s2&_eventId=foo`

Since the update, the link is missing the execution parameter, and resolves like this: `/fooaction/superflow?_eventId=foo`

This can be fixed, by changing the links, like this:

```
<g:link event="foo" params="${[execution: params.execution]}">Foo action</g:link>
```

But this can not be a solution. I searched the web and seem to be the only one having this problem. Which indicates I made a mistake in the configuration. Maybe someone can enlighten me, what I could have missed.

I found a [link on github](https://github.com/kastone/grails-webflow-sample/commit/969971ad724a835d533dd410099ed648e6ebecee#diff-59587ba940318a71a00f328a48c05176R13), stating `This works with <= Grails 2.4.4 but not with Grails >= 2.4.5. The execution param is missing`. Is this a bug which have not been fixed ever since?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For now I resolved this problem by using a custom tag Lib tag as wrapper for g:link, which includes the parameter `execution` if it is missing. I'd still happily will accept an answer which explains the current situation. Maybe webflow is deprecated?